# Could I pass an address of the first element of a vector of vector directly to a function which expects an unsigned char as its input?

Tags: c++, vector

everyone!
I have a vector of vector filled with unsigned chars. My function, which was imported from a third-party library, expects an unsigned char pointer as one of its input parameters. Could I pass an address of the first element of my vector of vector directly in the following form?

```
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char> > v2D;

// Some population code snippet goes here
.....

MyFuct(&v2D[0][0], .......);
```

I know that STL spec can guarantee vectors to store their elements contiguously. How about vector of vector? Must I convert a vector of vector to a single vector or an unsigned char array, and then pass to MyFuct? Thank you!

Comment: Think for a bit about how `std::vector<>` must be implemented. Because the storage can grow and must be contiguous, it can't reside *in* the vector object, which instead contains a pointer to a separate allocation that can *move* if there isn't enough room to grow in place. From there the answers below should be clear.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you must convert them into one vector, for the first vector doesn't need to be continuous with the second vector.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but you'd want to use &v2D[0] assuming it's declared as `std::vector < unsigned char > v2D`

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question, possibly while you were in mid-edit.  I had some issues getting my `< >` to show up as well.